# How to omit file extension from zsh autocomplete?

Tags: command-line, java, zsh

I'm new to zsh in Catalina. In .zshrc, I currently have

```
setopt CORRECT
setopt CORRECT_ALL
```

When I run a java program from the command line, I want only:

```
% java ProgramName
```

If I type `java Pro` autocomplete adds the rest of the name but also appends `.class`. (Or, if I have the source file in the same directory, it appends the `.` after the name) and I then have to delete `.class` (or hit the backspace once) before I can run the program.

Is there a way to get zsh autocomplete to omit `.class` (and `.`) but only when the initial command is `java`?

I'd prefer not to install something like Oh My Zsh which might alter my other zsh settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are still using Zsh's legacy completion system. You can upgrade to "new" completion system (released back in the year 2000) by adding this to your `.zshrc` file:

```sh
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Then you'll see that Zsh's `java` completion will no longer add `.class`.

Comment: @RPW Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding. Have since moved to Big Sur and this worked perfectly and have marked as such.